# MSI GP62M 7RDX with Ubuntu 16.04 on SSD and Win10 on HDD and I can't load Win10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

Neither bios, neither grub can't see Win10, but HDD is shown in bios and I can see all drive's information being using ubuntu 
How can I use Win10 or it would be better to wipe out all data from both disks and reinstall OSs ?
Thank's a lot in advance!